# regex results not past to fastcgi in nginx conf

Tags: nginx

Why does the php get called in this nginx.conf

```
    server_name ~^(.*)\.deploy.x.net$ ~^(.*)\.test2.x.net$;
    if (!-d /home/deploy/x.git/sub/$1) {
            rewrite . http://deploy.x.net/ redirect;
    }
    set $a  $1;
    root /home/deploy/x.git/sub/$a;
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

    #       # With php5-cgi alone:
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            # With php5-fpm:
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    }
```

but not when

```
root /home/deploy/x.git/sub/$1;
```

the result is a not found. Not sure why I need to declare a new variable for the root to get defined right for fastcgi...

Answer (score 0):

The document root is only being evaluated when it is needed. This is logical, because, for one thing, you can introduce several `root` directives in different contexts, and for another, the value of a variable part of the document root (`$1`, `$a`) can change from request to request, which makes it impossible to determine the right value beforehand.

So, in your case, the document root is evaluated inside the location context. And as your location is defined with a regular expression (~), in this context the `$1` variable is reassigned with an empty value, due to the absence of the group part `(...)` in your location regular expression.

You can work around this problem by adding a named capturing group, instead of relying on automatically assigned variables:

```
server_name ~^(?<folder>.*)\.deploy.x.net$ ~^(?<folder>.*)\.test2.x.net$;
...
root /home/deploy/x.git/sub/$folder;
```